# Why can you tittle a tittle but not an already tittled character like a j or an i?

Tags: html, utf-8, fonts, diacritics

In my attempt to convert a string to "[tittle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tittle) case" (in response to another question that possibly contained an orthographical error), it seems that some characters resist tittling.

> A tittle or superscript dot is a small distinguishing mark, such as a diacritic in the form of a dot on a lowercase i or j

The UTF-8 code point for a "dot above" (or tittle) is U+0307. If you combine the tittle with an already tittled i or j, the tittle is not visible (perhaps because it is positioned exactly where those characters already have tittles). However, you can tittle a tittle (which seems odd only because you can't tittle an already tittled character - not with a single tittle anyway). In addition, there are many UTF-8 code points such as U+25B2, black pointing up triangle, that prevent the tittle from being displayed above (which essentially makes the code point not a tittle or dot above at all).

So, what is the explanation for the UTF-8 tittle not always being displayed as a dot above (perhaps there is some limit to the range of code points with which diacritical marks can be combined OR font / html / browser rendering limitations)? Below is a snippet illustrating the various tittling issues referenced (Times New Roman is the default font in the browser I was using at the time I ran across this, so it is used in the snippet but there are likely a variety of different rendering issues in other fonts).

For those concerned this might be a dup, a search for tittle questions yields thousands of results, but, surprisingly, I could not find one that shed any light on my question.

UPDATE:
Although it did not occur to me initially, it should have been obvious that font selection makes all the difference as to whether or not you can tittle any particular character (since most fonts only attempt to faithfully render a subset of UTF-8 code points). The question that remains is whether or not there is a simple way to determine for a particular font which characters can be combined with diacritical marks, such as a tittle, or other [combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character), so that you can anticipate whether your tittle will actually be rendered as a dot above rather than a randomly placed dot.

```css
div {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
}
```

```html
<div>Invisible tittle over i: i&#x307</div>
<div>Visible tittle over another tittle: &#x307&#x307</div>
<div>Untittled tittle to right of triangle: &#x25B2&#x307</div>
<div>Visible tittle over i using double tittles: i&#x307&#x307</div>
```

Comment: I think it depends on the font you're using. For instance, I can see the tittle on the i on the first line; it looks a lot like the "Visible tittle over i using double tittles". But I don't have an answer, and this question has got me all titillated, so I'll see myself out...

Comment: Also, just a nit: you end your lines with `<div>`, not `</div>` which makes for an odd DOM. Doesn't affect anything, but just an oddity :). Oh, and my browser rendered the snippet result in Lucida Sans Unicode.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - thanks for catching the typo and for the font reference. The browser I am currently in is rendering the snippet result in Times New Roman.